# Selenium would not load up screen: Chrome Version:103.0.5060.53

Tags: python, linux, selenium, ubuntu, chromium

The issue is when I try to run a test with selenium in linux, the chrome ui does not appear, although I can see signs that the browser is active like the location where the browser should be getting getting laggy and my code reaching its checkpoints successfully. Only issue is I never see chrome ui. This only happens in ubuntu, the code runs fine on windows and mac.

Also, headless chrome is not active.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: we can't see your code, we can't run it - so we have no idea what is the problem. We don't know what page you load but maybe this page can detect Selenium and it blocks it.

Comment: Please provide the code you tried.so that we can help you